# Using global parameter in helm without running master chart

Tags: kubernetes-helm

### I have this structure of helm charts:

```
-chart A- \
                   -chart A1
                   -chart A2
-chart B- \
                   -chart B1
                   -chart B2
-chart C-\
                   -chart C1
                   -chart C3
```

What I need is a global parameter or environment variable that I can apply to **all**  charts without having a master chart above all charts.

So when I will run helm install I wouldnt have to pass this parameter using --set to all "main" charts (A,B,C).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give multiple `--set` and `-f` options to `helm install`, and so the best solution available is to write your "global" settings into a file and always pass a `-f global-settings.yaml` option to `helm install` (along with whatever other chart-specific settings and values files you have).

If everything you're installing is in a single namespace, depending on what the settings actually do, it may work to put them into a shared ConfigMap.  This is a little trickier to manage (you probably need to manually run `kubectl` commands), and there are many things you can do with Helm values that you couldn't with a shared ConfigMap.  But, it's "automatic" in the way you suggest in the question; you don't need any Helm options at all to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using a `xxx.yaml` file to override your charts default properties and template this file with that environment variable. I think that approach is much more maintainable than using `--set` cli option.

Another approach is using something like [Landscaper](https://github.com/Eneco/landscaper), listed on the [Helm documentatio](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/related.md)n, to template your charts ins an easy way